# How to use SQlite database using sqflite package in my Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm a beginner in flutter, I want to use SQLite database using `sqflite` package in my Flutter App,

when I use `import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';`I have a compilation error saying `Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart'. Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.`
and when I use
`io.Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();`
I have a compilation error saying

````
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getApplicationDocumentsDirectory'.```
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add path_provider dependency to your pubspec.yaml.

Add this:

```
dependencies:
  ...
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
```

Then run

```
flutter pub get
```

More info: https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Comment: or simply run ``flutter pub add path_provider`` cmd in the terminal :)